# Attempting to upload .png file to web directory

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, file-upload

I'm trying to use Unity to upload a .png file to a specific web folder.  The issue could be 1 of 3 things.

1) I couldn't locate a php.ini file on godaddy.  So could it be that the folder isn't configured for upload?

2) I've never done this in Unity before so it could be an issue with my code there.  (it does return the message that my file couldn't be uploaded, so it is pinging the .php file)

3) It could also be the php code I have, not sure if I adapted the example properly.

I've read other examples but I'm just not sure where my issue even lies for what I should be fixing.  Any advice would be awesome.

Unity:

```
public IEnumerator UploadTicketImage()
{
    byte[] FileUpload = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath 
        + "/TicketInformation/", "Pic001.png"));

    WWWForm TextureForm = new WWWForm();
    //TextureForm.AddBinaryData(PlayerPrefs.GetString("ImageName"), FileUpload);
    TextureForm.AddBinaryData("TotalTest", FileUpload, Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath 
        + "/TicketInformation/", "Pic001.png"),"image/png");

    UnityWebRequest wwwimageupload = UnityWebRequest.Post(StaticVars.IPAddress+ "/UploadTicketsImage.php?", TextureForm);

    wwwimageupload.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(FileUpload);
    //wwwimageupload.chunkedTransfer = false;

    yield return wwwimageupload.SendWebRequest();
    Debug.Log(wwwimageupload.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$target_dir = "PhotoDeposit/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Before trying to find 3 possible problem sources .. could you please state exactly what isn't working? Does your reading the file work properly? Does your request work(reach the server) at all? Before the `Debug.Log` I would add `if(wwwimageupload.isHttpError || wwwimageupload.isNetworkError) Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Unable to upload! Failed with {0} - {1}", wwwimageupload.responseCode, wwwimageupload.error); } else `

Comment: I'll post more information in a little bit after I try the suggestions you and the other poster made.  Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would already expect it to not find the image file you want to upload correctly.

```
Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath + "/TicketInformation/", "Pic001.png")
```

results in a path like

```
                   |                 |
                   v                 v

C:\path\to\project\/TicketInformation/\Pic001.png
```

on windows or

```
                 |                  |
                 v                  v

/path/to/project//TicketInformation//Pic001.png
```

on linux or android.

It should rather be used like

```
Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "TicketInformation", "Pic001.png")
```

and

```
Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "TicketInformation")
```

---

The next point is: Why are you even using an `UploadHandlerRaw` when you already added the data to the `WWWForm` so this seems to make not much sense to me.

You should remove the line

```
wwwimageupload.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(FileUpload);
```

---

Also note that [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.File.ReadAllBytes.html) only works on Windows platforms so depending on your build target you might have to change the way you read the file. You could use a [`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html) also to read local files. Something like

```
public IEnumerator UploadTicketImage()
{
    var folderPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "TicketInformation");
    var filepath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "Pic001.png");

    byte[] FileUpload = null;

    using (var www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(filepath))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "File loading failed with {0} - {1}", www.responseCode, www.error);
            Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Couldn't read file at {0}", filepath);
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            // file data successfully loaded
            FileUpload = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }

    var form = new WWWForm();
    // here you want the name the file should have on the server
    // not a complete system path to file on your local device
    //                                          |
    //                                          |
    //                                          |
    // And this is the field you will have      |
    // to access in php                         |
    //                  |                       |
    //                  v                       v
    form.AddBinaryData("TotalTest", FileUpload, "Pic001.png", "image/png");

    using (var www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://111.111.111.1" + "/UploadTicketsImage.php?", form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Finally I am no PHP expert by afaik you will then have to access the submitted field like

```
$_FILES['TotalTest']
```

sicne you call the field `TotalTest` in `form.AddBinaryData`.

Also the

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

is probably never true since you didn't set it in the `WWWForm` (I might be wrong and it is set automatically whenever a request is sent).

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear.*

Comment: I'm just sitting down to push through your suggestions.  Thank you though for your help.  I'll post back after I work through everything.

Comment: I debug logged the persistent data path and it reads correctly without any duplicate slashes.  I'm probably wrong, but I think unity uses the back slash in text for other commands and the reverse is used in strings.  I know I pull this picture from my windows folder for testing in the app, I haven't done so on the phone just yet though.  As for the PHP you were on the right track, I also had to change the text to 'TotalTest' in the other $_FILES and it worked.  Give me the name of a bar you like and I'll see if I can buy you one.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Also, could you edit that part of about replacing the name in all Files to total test?  I'm going to set it as the answer but it'd be nice to make sure someone else struggling doesn't miss out on that part.